# Flex-box: content rules the width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how flexible-box works in CSS.

I had great results with no contents in boxes, but, when i put some texts, the box(div) with the content rules the another box(div).

How i can use the flexible-box with the width/box "fixed", not fixed literally, but with no content rules the other boxes?

My Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLJDH/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
main > div {width: 50%;}
```

(As an aside, don't use more than one `main` element per page.)